# Show progress while sending multiple emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, nodemailer

I'm sending multiple emails from my node.js server and I want to show progress on frontend about how many mails have been sent.

I wrote code that sending response only after every email has been sent however i need notify frontend about progress.
As far as I know i cannot send multiple responses on single http request so i kinda lost here.

My emailsend request handler:

```
 const send = async (req, res) => {
    //parsing request body
    const {user, recievers, subject, text} = req.body;

    //Getting sender credentials from db
    const user = await UserSettings.findOne({ user }, 'MAIL');

    //creating nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: user.MAIL.SERVICE,
      auth: {
        user: user.MAIL.USER,
        pass: user.MAIL.PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    //sending email to every reciever
    recievers.forEach(reciever=> {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: user.MAIL.USER,
        to: reciever,
        subject,
        text
      };

      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (!error) {
          console.log(`Email sent: ${info.response}`);
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    });

    return res.sendStatus(204);
};
```

Comment: There are several technologies that can be used to notify client from server, such as polling, comet or websocket. You can make a simple search and find a lot of tutorials on the web.

Comment: @shaochuancs thank you, i have already thought about using web socet so i will probably will give it a try.